# Use a PHP variable in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, variables, onclick, javascript-framework

How can I use a PHP variable inside the Javascript `onclick=function`?

```
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo '<li><div><a  href="#" onclick="showPopUp("' . $mobile_image_link[$i+$p] .'","' .$mobile_image_link[$i+$p] .'");"><img src='. $mobile_image_link[$i+$p] .' width="160" height="165" alt="" border="0" /></a></div></div></li>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the strings, and use backslashes to escape the necessary quotes:

```
echo '
 <a href="#"
    onclick="showPopUp(\''. $mobile_image_link[$i+$p].'\',
                       \''. $mobile_image_link[$i+$p].'\');">
     <img src="'.$mobile_image_link[$i+$p].'" alt="" />
 </a>'
```

Would result in:

```
<a href="#"
    onclick="showPopUp('http://mylink.com/1',
                       'http://mylink.com/2');">
     <img src="http://mylink.com/image.png" alt="" />
 </a>
```

On a side note, please read the HTML latest specifications, setting tag style using `width=""`, `height=""` and `border=""` is deprecated and discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Simply echo php variable in javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var js_variable= <?php echo $php_variable; ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use the double quotes approach (php variables are only inserted into double quote strings.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  echo "<li><div><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"showPopUp('$mobile_image_link[$i+$p];','$mobile_image_link[$i+$p];');\"><img src=\"$mobile_image_link[$i+$p]\" width="160" height="165" alt="" border="0" /></a></div></div></li>";}
?>
```

or do what you already did for the img tag. You'll need to escape some quotes to make it work.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  echo '<li><div><a href="#" onclick="showPopUp(\''.$mobile_image_link[$i+$p].'\',\''.$mobile_image_link[$i+$p].'\');"><img src="'.$mobile_image_link[$i+$p].'" width="160" height="165" alt="" border="0" /></a></div></div></li>';}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
     $onclickvariable = "showPopUp('".$mobile_image_link[$i+$p]."','".$mobile_image_link[$i+$p]."');"
echo '<li><div><a  href="#" onclick="'.$onclickvariable.'">
     <img src='.$mobile_image_link[$i+$p].' width="160" height="165" alt="" border="0" /></a>
</div></li>';}
?>
```